# Textured triangle strips - rows beyond first row gives garbled output

Tags: opengl-es, textures, gl-triangle-strip

I'm drawing some "simple" 2D graphics using OpenGL ES, glDrawArrays and GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP.

I'm writing a function whose purpose is to take one 13x13 point (or other arbitrarily sized) texture and output it in specified number of columns and rows. So for 2 rows and 3 columns that would mean an area covered with 6 tiles over 26x39 points. The first row works well with the below code but as soon as I specify 2 or more rows there's just garbled output.

```
for (int row = 0; row < heightInTiles; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < widthInTiles; col++) {
        vertexIndexOffset += 8;
        startX = (GLshort)(col * TEXTUREWIDTH);
        startY = (GLshort)(row * TEXTUREHEIGHT);

        // Vertices
        vertices[vertexIndexOffset] = startX; // 1
        vertices[vertexIndexOffset + 1] = startY; //0.0;

        vertices[vertexIndexOffset + 2] = startX; // 2
        vertices[vertexIndexOffset + 3] = startY + (GLshort)TEXTUREHEIGHT;

        vertices[vertexIndexOffset + 4] = (GLshort)(startX + TEXTUREWIDTH); // 3
        vertices[vertexIndexOffset + 5] = startY;

        vertices[vertexIndexOffset + 6] = (GLshort)(startX + TEXTUREWIDTH); // 4
        vertices[vertexIndexOffset + 7] = startY + (GLshort)TEXTUREHEIGHT;

        // Texture coords
        uvs[vertexIndexOffset] = WRESULT; // 1
        uvs[vertexIndexOffset + 1] = 0;
        uvs[vertexIndexOffset + 2] = WRESULT; // 2
        uvs[vertexIndexOffset + 3] = HRESULTNEXT;
        uvs[vertexIndexOffset + 4] = WRESULTNEXT; // 3
        uvs[vertexIndexOffset + 5] = 0;
        uvs[vertexIndexOffset + 6] = WRESULTNEXT; // 4
        uvs[vertexIndexOffset + 7] = HRESULTNEXT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `heightInTiles=1` and `widthInTiles=2`, the code first generates two "stripped" triangles 1234; for the next cell, vertices 5678 are generated, where 3=5 and 4=6. So there are two *degenerate* triangles (having area `0`). However, this works (well, after moving `vertexIndexOffset += 8;` to the end of the inner loop)

```
 2----------4/6----------8
 |           |           |          
 |           |           |          
 |           |           |          
 |           |           |          
 1----------3/5----------7
```

Assuming `heightInTiles=2` and `widthInTiles=1`, the picture looks somewhat different:

```
 6-----------8
 |           |
 |           |
 |           |
 |           |
 2/5--------4/7
 |           |
 |           |
 |           |
 |           |
 1-----------3
```

Now, what happens if the *strip* 12345678 is drawn? 123, 234 is OK, but then 345? This overlaps, and note the texture coords for these vertices -- vertices 2 and 5 have different UVs! As above, there are two unwanted triangles, but this time, these don't have area `0` anymore.

When a new row is started, you need to insert two dummy vertices, essentially restarting the strip elsewhere. What if the triangle strip contained 1234`45`5678? Now, 123 and 234 are drawn OK, then 344, 445, 455, and 556 have area `0`, the next drawn triangles are 567 and 678.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. The placement of vertexIndexOffset += 8 was a mistake :-P